# Sinch(OTP verification) activity crashing

Tags: android, sinch, one-time-password

Trying to implement sinch, but the activity is crashing. I'm using Retrofit and Picasso. Can i use Sinch with them? I've also used other two classes too which are given in sinch tutorial. Here is my code

> MainActivity.java

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String SMS = "sms";
public static final String FLASHCALL = "flashcall";
public static final String INTENT_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";
public static final String INTENT_METHOD = "method";

private EditText mPhoneNumber;
private Button mSmsButton;
private Button mFlashCallButton;
private String mCountryIso;
private TextWatcher mNumberTextWatcher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
    mSmsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.smsVerificationButton);
    mFlashCallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callVerificationButton);

    mCountryIso = PhoneNumberUtils.getDefaultCountryIso(this);
    final String defaultCountryName = new Locale("", mCountryIso).getDisplayName();
    final CountrySpinner spinner = (CountrySpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.init(defaultCountryName);
    spinner.addCountryIsoSelectedListener(new CountrySpinner.CountryIsoSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCountryIsoSelected(String selectedIso) {
            if (selectedIso != null) {
                mCountryIso = selectedIso;
                resetNumberTextWatcher(mCountryIso);
                // force update:
                mNumberTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(mPhoneNumber.getText());
            }
        }
    });
    resetNumberTextWatcher(mCountryIso);

    tryAndPrefillPhoneNumber();
}

private void tryAndPrefillPhoneNumber() {
    if (checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mPhoneNumber.setText(manager.getLine1Number());
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 0);
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        tryAndPrefillPhoneNumber();
    } else {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permissions[0])) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This application needs permission to read your phone number to automatically "
                    + "pre-fill it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void openActivity(String phoneNumber, String method) {
    Intent verification = new Intent(this, VerificationActivity.class);
    verification.putExtra(INTENT_PHONENUMBER, phoneNumber);
    verification.putExtra(INTENT_METHOD, method);
    startActivity(verification);
}

private void setButtonsEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mSmsButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    mFlashCallButton.setEnabled(enabled);
}

public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    if (view == mSmsButton) {
        openActivity(getE164Number(), SMS);
    } else if (view == mFlashCallButton) {
        openActivity(getE164Number(), FLASHCALL);
    }
}

private void resetNumberTextWatcher(String countryIso) {

    if (mNumberTextWatcher != null) {
        mPhoneNumber.removeTextChangedListener(mNumberTextWatcher);
    }

    mNumberTextWatcher = new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(countryIso) {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            super.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            super.beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            super.afterTextChanged(s);
            if (isPossiblePhoneNumber()) {
                setButtonsEnabled(true);
                mPhoneNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                setButtonsEnabled(false);
                mPhoneNumber.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    };

    mPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(mNumberTextWatcher);
}

private boolean isPossiblePhoneNumber() {
    return PhoneNumberUtils.isPossibleNumber(mPhoneNumber.getText().toString(), mCountryIso);
}

private String getE164Number() {
    return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164(mPhoneNumber.getText().toString(), mCountryIso);
}
```

}

> activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/startbg"
android:padding="0dip"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/numberInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp">

    <com.sinch.verification.sample.CountrySpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/enterphonenumber"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbox"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
        android:textSize="32sp">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="40dp"
    android:paddingStart="40dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/smsVerificationButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_purple_generic"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        android:minWidth="132dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
        android:text="SMS Verification"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/callVerificationButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_purple_generic"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        android:minWidth="132dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
        android:text="Flash call Verification"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/numberInputLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/selectcountry"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

> CountrySpinner

```
    public class CountrySpinner extends Spinner {
private Map<String, String> mCountries = new TreeMap<String, String>();
private List<CountryIsoSelectedListener> mListeners = new ArrayList<CountryIsoSelectedListener>();

public interface CountryIsoSelectedListener {
    void onCountryIsoSelected(String iso);
}

public CountrySpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CountrySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void init(String defaultCountry) {
    initCountries();
    List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    countryList.addAll(mCountries.keySet());
    countryList.remove(defaultCountry);
    countryList.add(0, defaultCountry);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryList);

    setAdapter(adapter);

    setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            final String selectedCountry = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            notifyListeners(selectedCountry);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}

public void addCountryIsoSelectedListener(CountryIsoSelectedListener listener) {
    mListeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeCountryIsoSelectedListener(CountryIsoSelectedListener listener) {
    mListeners.remove(listener);
}

private void initCountries() {
    String[] isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
    for (String iso : isoCountryCodes) {
        String country = new Locale("", iso).getDisplayCountry();
        mCountries.put(country, iso);
    }
}

private void notifyListeners(String selectedCountry) {
    final String selectedIso = mCountries.get(selectedCountry);
    for (CountryIsoSelectedListener listener : mListeners) {
        listener.onCountryIsoSelected(selectedIso);
    }
}
```

}

> Logcat

```
7305-7305/earn.free.cashback.snapcash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:main
                                                                       Process: earn.free.cashback.snapcash, PID: 7305
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{earn.free.cashback.snapcash/earn.free.cashback.snapcash.Register}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void earn.free.cashback.snapcash.CountrySpinner.init(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void earn.free.cashback.snapcash.CountrySpinner.init(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at earn.free.cashback.snapcash.Register.onCreate(Register.java:49)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this should have been flagged as a duplicate. The former question was meant to address the general case of NPE whereas here, the Op is probably aware of what an NPE is but is wondering why that object isn't instantiated in the first place. The answer will be Android specific.

Comment: As @AmokraneChentir said, this is not a duplicate question, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to init the spinner in `onCreate()` when the view It's not already created. Try to do it in `onStart()` or `onResume()`.

Comment: Tried, not working. Actually when i downloaded the sample project and run it, it works fine. But when i integrate it in my project it crashes; I'm already integrated Facebook, Picasso and retrofit. Is it possible that they are causing some trouble?Can i use all of them in same project? I also tried digits and its not working either.

Comment: did you implement CountrySpinner class or is a library class?

Comment: class, not as library class

Comment: Could you share your class?

Comment: Done, I've added CountrySpinner.java class too

Comment: Great! Enjoy your code

Comment: I mean i've shared that class too

Comment: I just test your code and it's working on an emulator API 21, with only one change: mCountryIso = "ES";//PhoneNumberUtils.getDefaultCountryIso(this); Make sure defaultCountryName is not null

Comment: I think its because i'm using retrofit too.